# Перерасчет блоков, не учитывая hide

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
var a = $('div.wrapper > a');

var wid = a.length;

for( var i = 0; i < wid; i+=8 ) {
    a.slice(i, i+8).wrapAll('<div class="slide"></div>');
}; 

$(".pro").click(function() {
 $(".pro1").toggle('hide');  
 return false;
});
});
```

```css
.slide{ 
   background: red;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#" class="pro1"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="pro">Клик</a>
```

Есть такой код. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, был перерасчет length и в первый блок добавлялась 8ая картинка, когда исчезает из этого блока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так примерно должно работать при клике

Comment: Я ничего не понял. В блоке 13 картинок, жму кнопку и одна убирается, становится 12. Жму снова и добавлятся опять 13ая

Comment: Если нужно получить кол-во не скрытых блоков `$('.wrapper a:visible').length`

Comment: Когда я нажимаю на "Клик", элемент с классом pro1 скрывается. В первом красном блоке исчезает одна картинка. Необходимо чтобы после исчезновения pro1 был перерасчет сколько всего элементов в $('div.wrapper > a'). Должен учитываться hide.

Comment: Что значит должен учитываться? Тоесть его не считать, если он скрытый?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, скрываем картинку и длина должна составлять 12 картинок?

Comment: Всё верно, он не должен учитываться после скрытия. Но после показала, длина должна быть также больше

Answer (score 1):

Обновляется длина по окончанию анимации.
Получить все видимые элементы можно таким образом `$('.wrapper a:visible')`

`eq()` - порядок строки, `eq(0)` верхняя, `eq(1)` - нижняя

```js
var a = $('div.wrapper > a');
wid = a.length;

for(i=0; i<wid; i+=8) {
    a.slice(i, i+8).wrapAll('<div class="slide"></div>');
}

$(".pro").click(function() {
    $(".pro1").toggle('hide', function() {
        wid = $('.slide').eq(0).find('a:visible').length;
    });

    return false;
});

$('button').click(function() {
    console.log(wid);
});
```

```css
.slide{ 
    background: red;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="pro1"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
</div>

<a href="" class="pro">Клик</a>
<button>Длина</button>
```

Comment: Когда скрывается элемент с картинкой, в верхнем красном блоке должно быть всё-равно 8 элементов, а в нижнем соответственно уменьшаться, то есть 4 элемента, потому, что один из низ был перемещён вверх.
В каждом <div class="slide"></div> должно быть строго 8 элементов, конечно если они есть все 8, а если больше. можно видеть что создаётся ещё один <div class="slide"></div> и так дальше

Comment: @ЭнтролАртимов, сейчас то, что нужно?

Comment: Прикрепил гифку в первом посте.

Comment: @ЭнтролАртимов, так это вообще не перерасчёт длины, это перенос изображения из нижней части в верхнюю. Вопрос-то правильно формулировать надо

Comment: Обновил гифку, должно сдвигаться

Comment: не совсем перенос. Сам <div class="slide"></div> добавляется когда элементов в списке больше 8 и так каждые 8. Например в разметке будет 24 элемента и будет три красных блока. Что мне нужно? Если я скрыл один из элементов например в начале, 3-й по счету от верха, должно это всё учитываться, длина всех элементов 23 уже. Значит в самом нижнем красном блоке будет уже не 8, а 7. А вверху всё так и останется. Я скрываю вверху допустим, но блок всегда должен быть заполнен в 8 элементов.